# add rethinkdb in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rethinkdb

I have docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  build: ./app
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
  links:
    - "db:redis"
  command: nodemon -L app/bin/www


db:
  image: redis
```

I woud like add rethinkdb into docker-compose.yml. I know what create a image with a command `docker run -d -P --name rethink1 rethinkdb` but i don't understood how add this service in my `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it like the other services that you have.

```
web:
  build: ./app
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
  links:
    - "db:redis"
  command: nodemon -L app/bin/www

db:
  image: redis

rethinkdb:
  image: rethinkdb
  container-name: rethink1
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Do need add in links: -rethink1 ?

Comment: No, your containers are already on the same network, so they can communicate with each other without using links.